# Failed to extract the keys from a jsonDecoded variable in flutter

Tags: json, flutter, dart, flutter-dependencies

I am a new to flutter. I am trying to get all the keys from the jsonDecoded variable. I have trying everything i know to get those keys. but i could not do so.

So my question is how can i get all the keys from the jsonDecoded value with the easiest and shortest possible way?

Here is my code:

```
    Future<String> getData() async {
    var response = await http.get(
        Uri.encodeFull(
            "https://my-json-server.typicode.com/dipcse07/demoJSON/db"),
        headers: {"Accept": "application/json"});

    //print(response.body);
    print('tapped');

    setState(() {
      data = jsonDecode(response.body.toString());

      collegeDataLenght = data['CollegeName1'].length;
      count = collegeDataLenght;
      teachersInfo = data['CollegeName1'];
      print(teachersInfo[0]['avatarImage']);
 });
}
```

*****NEED TO GET ALL THE KEYS FROM `data`**

the data i am getting from my api link is

```
{
   "CollegeName1":[
      {
         "teacherName":"Md Sazid hasan dip",
         "teacherID":"2345",
         "avatarImage":"url",
         "address":"9/2, shenbari Road, Shanki Para Bazar Mymensingh",
         "status":"Active",
         "joinDate":"date",
         "resignDate":"present"
      },
      {
         "TeacherName":"Talha Azadi",
         "teacherID":"2345",
         "avatarImage":"url",
         "address":"9/2, shenbari Road, Shanki Para Bazar Mymensingh",
         "status":"Active",
         "joinDate":"date",
         "resignDate":"present"
      }
   ],
   "CollegeName2":[
      {
         "teacherName":"Md Sazid hasan dip",
         "teacherID":"2345",
         "avatarImage":"url",
         "address":"9/2, shenbari Road, Shanki Para Bazar Mymensingh",
         "status":"Active",
         "joinDate":"date",
         "resignDate":"present"
      },
      {
         "TeacherName":"Talha Azadi",
         "teacherID":"2345",
         "avatarImage":"url",
         "address":"9/2, shenbari Road, Shanki Para Bazar Mymensingh",
         "status":"Active",
         "joinDate":"date",
         "resignDate":"present"
      }
   ]
}
```

Comment: Do you just want "CollegeName1" and "CollegeName2"?

Comment: yes. and if posibble all the keys

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You parsed json will return a [`Map`](https://api.dart.dev/stable/dart-core/Map-class.html) which has a [`.keys`](https://api.dart.dev/stable/dart-core/Map/keys.html) property you can use:

```
void main() {
  final parsedJson = jsonDecode(json) as Map<String, dynamic>;
  print(parsedJson.keys);
}
```

Comment: jsonDecode(). does not shows any .key function in the ide suggestion.. i am using android studio and  my environment details:

version: 1.0.0+1

environment:
  sdk: ">=2.1.0 <3.0.0"

Comment: It is because Dart cannot know for sure what kind of data you get after the decoding since JSON allows multiple types. So Dart can only set the type as `dynamic` which means "ok, I don't know what you want but lets see if it works when the program are running". This is the reason why I make the cast `as List<String>` (just to be sure about the type since the program would crash if the result was not `List<String>`. But because the JSON input are dynamic you are not going to get much help from the IDE.

Comment: I have updated the answer to make more sense and also allow you to get some suggestions from the IDE from the `parsedJson`.

Comment: Just notice that Dart again cannot say something in general about the type of the values in the Map so the type will again here be `dynamic`. :)

Comment: That worked.!!.. thanks man.. i could not even find it out in the documentation.. of dart convert https://api.dart.dev/stable/2.8.4/dart-convert/dart-convert-library.html that's why i was confused..